# Server shutting down sometimes - Node.js express.js socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

For some reason unknown my server is shutting down and I have login on server and run my app again. Someone had that problem?

Here is my log.

```
info: socket.io started  
debug: client authorized  
info: handshake authorized m2-7nzTeYuhWz7aT9-AQ  
debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/m2-7nzTeYuhWz7aT9-AQ  
debug: set heartbeat interval for client m2-7nzTeYuhWz7aT9-AQ  
debug: client authorized for  
debug: websocket writing 1::  
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"connect","args":[{"objSeats":{"4536":{"5851":{"6":[]}}}}]}  
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"connect","args":[{"objSeats":{"4536":{"5851":{"6":[]}}}}]}  
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"connect","args":[{"objSeats":{"4536":{"5851":{"6":[]}}}}]}  
info: transport end (socket end)  
debug: set close timeout for client fgFEi9a8ZCJ4vGe49-AO  
debug: cleared close timeout for client fgFEi9a8ZCJ4vGe49-AO  
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client fgFEi9a8ZCJ4vGe49-AO  
debug: discarding transport  
info: transport end (socket end)  
debug: set close timeout for client vbWkAQBC6rMIiOl99-AP  
debug: cleared close timeout for client vbWkAQBC6rMIiOl99-AP  
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client vbWkAQBC6rMIiOl99-AP  
debug: discarding transport  
info: transport end (socket end)  
debug: set close timeout for client m2-7nzTeYuhWz7aT9-AQ  
debug: cleared close timeout for client m2-7nzTeYuhWz7aT9-AQ  
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client m2-7nzTeYuhWz7aT9-AQ  
debug: discarding transport  
debug: client authorized  
info: handshake authorized i5J-qT9e34ta2l3J9-AR  
debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/i5J-qT9e34ta2l3J9-AR  
debug: set heartbeat interval for client i5J-qT9e34ta2l3J9-AR  
debug: client authorized for  
debug: websocket writing 1::  
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"connect","args":[{"objSeats":{"4536":{"5851":{"6":[]}}}}]}  
info: transport end (socket end)  
debug: set close timeout for client i5J-qT9e34ta2l3J9-AR  
debug: cleared close timeout for client i5J-qT9e34ta2l3J9-AR  
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client i5J-qT9e34ta2l3J9-AR  
debug: discarding transport  
debug: client authorized  
info: handshake authorized RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: set heartbeat interval for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: client authorized for  
debug: websocket writing 1::  
debug: websocket writing 5:::{"name":"connect","args":[{"objSeats":{"4536":{"5851":{"6":[]}}}}]}  
debug: emitting heartbeat for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: websocket writing 2::  
debug: set heartbeat timeout for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: got heartbeat packet  
debug: cleared heartbeat timeout for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: set heartbeat interval for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
info: transport end (undefined)  
debug: set close timeout for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: cleared close timeout for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: cleared heartbeat interval for client RJTRf_Jy2WX-uUej9-AS  
debug: discarding transport
```

Comment: that means you have an error in your code. read documentation again or remove some part of code to find out an error. go back when your app was working well.

Comment: Its something to do with the client timeout and heartbeat interval. i know i didnt say much but helped narrow the search atleast. yay just made my first stack flow comment #whoopWhoop